# How to ignore timezone when using bson.json_util.loads in python?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pymongo, bson

I'm dumping and loading bson to text files and my datetimes are having time zone info added to them. I do not want the time zone info added.

```
import bson, datetime
d1 = datetime.datetime.now()
d2 = bson.json_util.loads(bson.json_util.dumps(d1))
```

Results in d1:

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 16, 14, 38, 41, 984544)
```

and d2 :

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 16, 14, 56, 10, 155000, tzinfo=<bson.tz_util.FixedOffset object at 0x1042ca050>)
```

In this particular case I can do

```
d3 = d2.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

to remove the timezone. However, I'm doing this for a larger object with times all over the place among other types. Is there a way to instruct `bson.json_util.loads` to always set `tzinfo=None` when it tries to parse a datetime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting. The `bson` source directly overwrites `object_hook` so you can't pass in a custom one.

From the [source here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/bson/json_util.py):

```
def loads(s, *args, **kwargs):
    """Helper function that wraps :class:`json.loads`.
    Automatically passes the object_hook for BSON type conversion.
    """
    kwargs['object_hook'] = lambda dct: object_hook(dct)
    return json.loads(s, *args, **kwargs)
```

Their source (inside `object_hook`) is also explicitly setting the timezone, which is causing the behavior that you're seeing:

```
aware = datetime.datetime.strptime(
            dt, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").replace(tzinfo=utc)

if not offset or offset == 'Z':
    # UTC
    return aware
```

I think you're going to have to do another pass over your resulting data set to remove the time zones, if you absolutely can't have a time zone set.

**EDIT**: It looks like there is a [pending change](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/57d1ccde2fdb7c7861b1ff0ae8f3bf325f793b42/bson/json_util.py) to add a `JsonOptions` class that would allow you to pass `tz_aware=False`. So if you can wait until the python driver updates to 3.4, you should be able to get your desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Found myself here in 2021. This is how I resolved it:

```
import bson, datetime
d1 = datetime.datetime.now()
json_options = json_util.DEFAULT_JSON_OPTIONS.with_options(tz_aware=False, tzinfo=None)

d2 = bson.json_util.loads(bson.json_util.dumps(d1), json_options=json_options)
```

Comment: This throw this error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    json_options = json_util.DEFAULT_JSON_OPTIONS.with_options(tz_aware=False, tzinfo=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bson/json_util.py", line 410, in loads
    return json.loads(s, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 352, in loads
    return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 357, in __init__
    self.scan_once = scanner.make_scanner(self)
TypeError: encoding must be a string, not CodecOptions

Comment: @ReaHaas I just ran this on my machine and it works. Which version are you using?